# Database Queries With Express

Tags: sql, postgresql, express

Can anyone help. I am trying to get a row from database table when id = 1 (or other)?

When I try `localhost:3000/product/1` in a browser, it does not work.

This is my code:

```
const { query } = require('../db/db');

const getAllProducts = (request, response) => {
  query('SELECT * FROM product', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

// Check if response is defined before using it
    if (response && response.status) {
      response.status(200).json(results.rows);
    } else {
      console.error('Response object is undefined or missing status property.');
    }
  });
};

// http://localhost:3000/product/1
const getProductById = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id, 10)
  console.log(`id query run id=${id}`)
  query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    // Check if response is defined before using it
    if (response && response.status) {
      response.status(200).json(results.rows);
    } else {
       console.error('Response object is undefined or missing status property.');
    }
 });
};

module.exports = {
  getAllProducts,
  getProductById
};
```

If I change to:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = 1
```

it will return product with id of 1 as expected.

The console.log all look good and seems to be something wrong with the id I am passing to $1 but I can see this value changing to 1, 2, 3 correctly in the console.logs.

Thanks for any help

Comment: does it throw any error? what does `console.log(response)` tell you?

Comment: added .then
after query
.then((results) => {
      // Check if response is defined before using it
      if (response && response.status) {
        response.status(200).json(results.rows);
      } else {
        console.error('Response object is undefined or missing status property.');
      }
    })
and works

any advice why

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = ?', [id], (error, results) =>
```

Comment: I haven't. I have another project with that string layout and it works OK. I'll give it a try when back at my pc. Cheers